# Uniform asymptotic expansion

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

Let the function $f(x,\nu)$, with $x>0$ and $\nu\in[0,+\infty)$, have the asymptotic expansion
\begin{equation}
f(x,\nu)\sim\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}(\nu)x^{n}\;,
\end{equation} 
as $x\to 0$. Assume also that $|a_{n}(\nu)|\leq M_{n}$ for some constant $M_{n}$ for $\nu\in[0,+\infty)$. Can one conclude that the above asymptotic expansion is *uniform* in the variable $\nu$? namely can one conclude that 
\begin{equation}
f(x,\nu)=\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_{n}(\nu)x^{n}+O(x^{N+1})\;,
\end{equation} 
with $O(x^{N+1})$ independent of $\nu$?

Comment: @Antonio Vargas. I can see that there might be problems with uniformity when the function depends on the ratio $\nu/x$. Let us say, then, that for the functions $a_{n}(\nu)$ we have $a_{n}(\nu)=e^{-\nu}P_{n}(\nu)$ with $\nu\in[0,+\infty)$. $P_{n}(\nu)$ denotes a polynomial of degree less or equal than $n$. Can, in this case, one conclude that the expansion is uniform in $\nu$? Basically what I would like to do is justify the term-by-term integration w.r.t $\nu$ of the asymptotic series (provided that the integrals exist) to get an asymptotic series of $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x,\nu)d\nu$.

Comment: I think my example is still a counterexample for that case.  If I'm not mistaken, just multiply it by $e^{-\nu}$.  I'm skeptical that any conclusion about uniformity can be drawn from the coefficients of the asymptotic series.

Answer (score 1):

In general no.  For example, $e^{-\nu^2/x^2} = O(x^n)$ as $x \to 0$ for all $n \geq 0$ and $\nu \neq 0$ fixed, so we have

$$
\frac{1}{1-x} + e^{-\nu^2/x^2} \sim \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$$ as $x \to 0$ for all fixed $\nu \neq 0$.  This asymptotic is not uniform with respect to $\nu$ when, say, $\nu = x$.